# Raw expression in Vue.js: error in computing class dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vue.js 2.0 I'm trying to make a compute a class like this:

```
 <li :class="'str1'   calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)">                                               </li>
```

And in methods I have:

```
methods: {
     calcStarClass(starNum, rating) {
         switch (starNum) {
             case 1:
                 switch (rating) {
                     case (rating == 0):
                         return "str"
                         break;
                     case (0 < rating < 1):
                         return "strh"
                         break;
                     case (rating >= 1):
                         return "strf"
                         break;
                     default:
                         return "strf"
                 }
                 break;
             case 2: ...
```

But I get this error:

```
Raw expression: :class="'str1'   calcStarClass(1, p.rtn)"
```

When I try `<li v-bind:class="'str1'   calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)">` instead, I get this error:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

    'str1'   calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)

  Raw expression: v-bind:class="'str1'   calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)"
```

I'm wondering what casuse this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `v-bind`, it expects a valid javascript expression, but `'str1'   calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)` is not a valid javascript expression. Use `+` to concatenate multiple classes if that's what you need:

```
<li :class="'str1 ' + calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)">
```

Answer (score 2):

you could update it like this one

```
 <li :class="['str1', calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)]">
```

Another way

```
 <li class="str1" :class="calcStarClass(1, p.rtg)">
```